# Combine/Splice pandas DataFrames with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I have two pandas dataframes, **A** and **B**.
The dataframes have the same index and columns just different data.
I have an additional array **X** which is a subset of the index.

What I want to achieve:
The resulting matrix **C** which also has the same index and columns as **A** and **B**. For its data it takes the row entry from dataframe **A** if the index is in **X** otherwise it takes the row entry from **B**.

I thought there would be a pythonic way to achieve this but they don't compile. So for example I create a **C** dataframe with **A**'s index and then tried things like:

```
C = C.apply(lambda i: A.ix[i.index] if i in X else B.ix[i.index])
```

I have something working at the moment where I basically solve it mathematically. So I create two boolean arrays based on **X** to specify which entries I want from **A** and **B** respectively. I then multiply **A** and **B** by those matrices and then do **C** = **A** + **B**. This seems VERY long winded to achieve the solution. I was after something shorter and more readable. My current solution looks like:

```
def testIn(row):
    return [x in X for x in row.index]
def testOut(row):
    return [x not in X for x in row.index]

AMAP = C.apply(testIn, axis=0)
BMAP = C.apply(testOut, axis=0)

ANEW = pandas.DataFrame(AMAP*A)
BNEW = pandas.DataFrame(BMAP*B)

C = ANEW + BNEW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following data

```
B = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((6, 6)), list('ABCDEF'), list('abcdef'))
A = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((6, 6)), B.index, B.columns)
x = ['A', 'D']
```

[`pd.DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) takes the the values from the first dataframe and supplements with the second.  But using `loc` over the the list `x`, I limit `A` to just the rows I want and combine the rest of `B`.

```
C = A.loc[x].combine_first(B)

print(C)

     a    b    c    d    e    f
A  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
C  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
D  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
E  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
F  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

***other alternatives***

```
A.query('index in @x').combine_first(B)
```

---

```
B.drop(x).append(A.loc[x]).reindex_like(A)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
C = A.copy()
C.update(B.iloc[X])
```

You basically take a copy of one of your dataframes and update the records from the other one filtered against the index that matches.

If you want to spare the full copy of A into C, you can partition A and B against X:

```
C = A[~A.index.isin(X)]
C = C.append(B.iloc[X]).reindex(A.index)
```

Comment: Of course update! Thank you. I was using this elsewhere but overlooked it as a solution here.